# iterator tag of struts2

Tags: java, struts2

i m using struts2 nested iterator tag in my code all i want is that the inner iterator tag should execute once for each time the outer iterator tag execute 
how can i achieve it (any break statement kind thing???)

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">Male</div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">Female</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">No.</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">%</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">No.</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">%</div></td>
  </tr>
  <s:set name="list" value="#request.name" />
  <s:set name="list1" value="#request.name1" />

  <s:iterator value="list" var="var">
  <s:iterator value="list1" var="var1">
  <tr>
    <td><s:property value="var" /></td>
     <td><s:property value="var1" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr> 

  </s:iterator>
  </s:iterator>
```

Comment: there is not direct beak statement, but can be done using if tag.Can you describe what exact is your requirement?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi : `<s:if>` tags will not stop the loop to iterate. It will help avoiding the processing. He wants like a `break` statement in `for-loop`

Comment: @tusar:agree and i am not sure what he wants exactly and more over begin there is no direct way you can exit from the iterator tag

Comment: problem solved!!!
thanx though  :)

Answer (score 0):

See [Struts2 tag reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/iterator.html):

```
<s:iterator value="list" var="var">
   <s:iterator value="list1" var="var1" begin="1" end="1">
   <tr>
     <td><s:property value="var" /></td>
     <td><s:property value="var1" /></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr> 

 </s:iterator>
 </s:iterator>
```

Update:

Don't know why its showing the undefined attribute error. Probably you are not using latest struts2.2.1 jars. You could use `status="stat" value="{1}"` also for 1-time iteration. here is the example:

```
<s:iterator value="list" var="var">
   <s:iterator value="list1" var="var1" status="stat" value="{1}">
   <tr>
     <td><s:property value="var" /></td>
     <td><s:property value="var1" /></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr> 

 </s:iterator>
 </s:iterator>
```

Comment: it says Undefined attribute name "begin" and "end "

Comment: hi Ashish, i have updated the answer. just let me know if it you get any error